# HUD is not working after upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade, hud

My HUD is not working after I upgraded from 11.04 (and or 11.10).

It prompts for command and it tries loading for 4 seconds then gives up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it will work after you install this package.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my HUD problem by clearing out the ~/.cache folder.

Comment: Did you upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10? Otherwise I bet your problem was different than OP's.